# Is this an atomic update? Why way is better

Tags: sql-server

So, despite having being doing this sql server thing for a while, I find myself second guessing myself on this one.

Scenario: I want to sell something, but I don't want to over-sell it. This is query I have. (@Quantity is usually a negative number, SalesItemId is the primary key of the table). It seems like a nice neat solution

```
UPDATE SalesItem 
SET QtyAvailable = QtyAvailable + @Quantity
WHERE SalesItemId = @Id
AND QtyAvailable +  @Quantity >= 0

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0   BEGIN 
   RAISERROR ('Cannot sell item, would sell out')
END
```

Will this do the update and where query in the same trasaction, thus preventing getting a QtyAvailable less than zero? I would have thought so, but I get instances of where I end up selling more items that I should. I always figured it was another part of the system, but all fingers appear to point to this query?

Is it better to do two stage process? eg. This (or the converse of checking before updating)

```
BEGIN TRAN
    UPDATE SalesItem 
    SET QtyAvailable = QtyAvailable + @Quantity
    WHERE SalesItemId = @Id

    IF ( SELECT  QtyAvailable > FROM SalesItem where SalesItemId = @Id) < 0
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('Cannot sell item, would sell out')
        ROLLBACK TEAN
        RETURN 
    END 
COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: Try using the `with (SERIALIZABLE)` hint (or set the transaction isolation level to serializable.   This should prevent inconsistent transactions.  But, there could be a performance cost.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I guess the SERIALIZABLE isolation level do not help much on this IF `SalesItemId` is the key of the table. The update query selects only one single table and it already applied the U-Lock.

Comment: (I failed to mention that - now edited) SalesItemId is the primary key of the table.

Comment: You say "update and where query" - it's only a single statement, not two.

Comment: I prefer the 2 stage process. However, I would recommend UPDATE before the SELECT, because the UPDATE, on most RMDB Platforms, by default, should implicitly lock the row, which you do want. If you were to do the SELECT first, you need to explicitly LOCK the row, unless you want to encounter concurrency issues. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your single update statement is an atomic transaction.  It seems efficient and elegant as it stands.  If you're getting negative QtyAvaliable values, you should check all other instances of your code that modify it's value.

You said usually @Quantity is a negative number.  Make sure that if you have instances where you want to add a positive quantity and then subtract it with an offsetting transaction that these are done together in a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO burying business logic in the database is a mistake (leave it in the app - easier to test, change, debug, write, etc, etc), but if you absolutely must (eg there is no "app" - you're using a tool that use SQL to action things, or you have a legacy situation of many apps relying on the database doing the work), I would:

- create a trigger on insert (and update, delete) of an order line item that updates the product's stock level
- create a check constraint on the product that requires the stick level to be non-zero

Then atomicity is wired into the insert  (or update or delete) statement, as triggers/checks are fired in the same transaction as the event that fires them.

Put simply, with this in place it will be impossible for any order-data-changing query to cause a situation where a negative stock level exists.